# Dynamic column in oracle sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I want to query in database for some ledgername (like child),ledgergroupname (like parent,it's parent of ledgername) and all ascending parent's of ledgergroupname (or ledgername).Data i am searching from ACC_LEDGER table where ledgername and it's immediate parent termed as ledgergroupname are saved.Ascending parent of ledgergroupname are saved in ACC_LEDGERGROUP table.
sql--

```
select 
pp.Ledgercode,
pp.Ledgername,
pp.Ledgergroupcode,
pp.Ledgergroupname,
(select Acc_Ledgergroup.Parentname from Acc_Ledgergroup where Acc_Ledgergroup.Ledgergrpcode=pp.Ledgergroupcode) as PARENTNAME

from     
    (select 
    LED.LEDGERCODE,
    Led.Ledgername,
    Led.Ledgergroupcode,
    Led.Ledgergroupname
    from ACC_LEDGER LED where Led.Ledgercode IN ('01003024007','01003024019'))pp
```

it gives me result--
[image]
 what i want is --
[image]

so for every ledger i want to show parent upto root (it's level is different for different ledger means for some ledger it has 7 upper parent's to reach "root" parent).

I am trying to query something like this(it's for your understanding)--

```
select
pp.Ledgercode,
pp.Ledgername,
pp.Ledgergroupcode,
pp.Ledgergroupname,

(select Acc_Ledgergroup.Parentname from Acc_Ledgergroup where Acc_Ledgergroup.Ledgergrpcode=pp.Ledgergroupcode) as PARENTNAME


while(parentname != root)
{
  select parent name from Ledger group 
}
from the_table
```

**So column selection from table or join of table is not fixed,it's depend on how much level of parent i have,how can i do that in oracle sql?**

Comment: Lookup recursive hierarchical query.

Comment: i tried start and connect by also,but can not reach to solution

Comment: Must you have separate columns for each parent or /root/primary/Current Asset will do? If not, what happens for different levels - say for one row number of parent are 5 and for other one say, 10? You'd be better off doing all this in you application code.

Comment: @GurV i want to write query that my result column number will be according to my parent level.Ex. if one record has 3 parent then column will be 5 (3+ledgername+ledgergroupname) , if another record has two parent then it will show null for 1 column --like this

Comment: Is there a maximum limit to the number of parent?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @GurV there is no limit . it will not exceed 10.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what you want to show by this link,don't understand

Comment: *It will not exceed 10* means exactly that there **is** limit, the limit is 10. Please clarify what you meant with that answer. Then: If the limit is 10 and you don't mind having up to 10 columns in all cases, even if the result only uses at most five of them, then it can be done in SQL. Otherwise (if the number of columns should be determined by the data) it can **not** be done in plain SQL, you will need dynamic SQL. Why do you need the result in that format, anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Generally this kind of problems can be solved with hierarchical queries (using `CONNECT BY`), however in Oracle a query cannot have a variable number of columns. As a workaround you can use `sys_connect_by_path` to concatenate all levels using some separator:

```
select sys_connect_by_path(Ledgergroupname, '/')
  from Acc_Ledgergroup
 where Ledgergroupname = 'root'
 start with Ledgercode in ('01003024007', '01003024019')
 connect by prior Ledgercode = Ledgergroupcode
```